# Why is Tensorflow tf.train.exponential_decay called exponential decay?

Tags: machine-learning

Doesn't [tf.train.exponential_decay](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/exponential_decay) do a step decay when 'staircase = true', as described in [CS231n Course Notes](http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-3/#anneal), rather than an exponential decay?
As far as I know, the tf.train.exponential_decay function does not involve the exponential $e^x$ so why is it called exponential decay? Wouldn't a better name be step decay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Exponential function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function)  is a function of the form $f(x)=ab^x$, not just $e^x$. And the formula for the decayed exponential is:

```
decayed_learning_rate = learning_rate *
                        decay_rate ^ (global_step / decay_steps)
```

as given in your link, which is quite similar with the mathematical definition. When staircase is true, they just apply integer division. It is still in a generalized version of exponential form, i.e. $ab^{g(x)}$, where $g(x)$ is the integer division. So, the naming is consistent. You can’t cover all with ‘step’ keyword. And, the default behavior is without the staircase, so is in a pure exponential form.